# DES implementation in Java. Can not get the plaintext

Tags: java, security, encryption, des

I am working in a simple example for DES implementation using Java built-in libraries. This is my code:

```
import it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class DES {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        String msg="This is a secret message";
        byte [] msgBytes=msg.getBytes();        
        byte [] keyBytes  = {(byte)0xFE, (byte)0xDC, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0x98, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x54, (byte)0x32, (byte)0x10};
        SecretKeySpec myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");

        //to encrypt a message
        String cipher=encryptMsg(msgBytes, myDesKey);

        //to decrypt a message
        String plain = decryptMsg(cipher.getBytes(), myDesKey);

        System.out.println("Original Message: "+ msg);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Message: "+ cipher);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Message: "+ plain);

    } //end main

    //encryption function
    public static String encryptMsg(byte [] msgBytes, SecretKey myDesKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        Cipher desCipher;
        // Create the cipher 
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
        byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(msgBytes);

        // converts to base64 for easier display.
        byte[] base64Cipher = Base64.encode(textEncrypted);
        return new String(base64Cipher);
    } //end encryptMsg

    public static String decryptMsg(byte [] cipherBytes, SecretKey myDesKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        Cipher desCipher; 
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
        byte[] textDecrypted=desCipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);

        // converts to base64 for easier display.
        byte[] base64Plain = Base64.encode(textDecrypted);
        return new String(base64Plain);
    } //end decryptMsg
} //end class
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Original Message: This is a secret message
Encrypted Message: hNFgTAoz2TN9f6FcLdbjnEBe5DrsU4sm
Decrypted Message: RFdk1JK0gG0vv2zndHueS9rRe0Oux44ACGObsRHQ+4E=
```

I need my key to be a fixed (not random) value. That's why I defined it as array of bytes in the beginning.

My problem is that my decryption function does not return the original message. This means there is a problem in the code and probably the encryption is not proper. I am suspicious about the coding issue as the encryption / decryption is quite straight forward. Can you point the problems in my code?

**EDIT:**
In the decryption, I changed the `encode` to `decode` as suggested by one of the comments. That does not work. I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected I/O error
    at it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64.decode(Unknown Source)
    at DES.decryptMsg(DES.java:55)
    at DES.main(DES.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad base64 stream
    at it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64InputStream.acquire(Unknown Source)
    at it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64.copy(Unknown Source)
    at it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64.decode(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Both times you doing encode (when trying to encode and decode) maybe you should change encode to decode method in decryptMsg? So you're doing encode operation twice

Answer (score 1):

You're not decoding the encryption of the original message; you're decoding the *base64 encoding* of the encryption original message.

Rather than passing `cipher.getBytes()`, you need `Base64.decode(cipher).getBytes()`, or, alternatively, have the method accept a base64 String and handle the decoding in the method.

Also, there's no need to base64 decode the decrypted content. It will already be in the original encoding. In other words, just return `new String(textDecrypted)`.

---

The flow you're trying to do is: plaintext -> encrypted content -> base64 -> encrypted content -> plaintext. The flow you're doing is text -> encrypted content -> base64 -> decrypted base64 (nonsense) -> base64 (nonsense)